# How to filter by month in view using a date field

Tags: views, datetime

I have a field called `birthday` that is defined for users. In `views`, is there any way to create a filter that filters only by month? Smallest values it lets me select is year and month where I only need month. (to find users who are born in April for example). Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module, then you can set the `granularity` to `month` in the date filter settings.

Then, you can configure the filter like so `Operator: "is equal to"` and `Date: "this month"`.

If you don't see these filter settings, you would have to enable the `date_views` module.

Comment: I have set the granularity to only month, but on the configure screen, it forces me to select a year too. See the screen shot please.

Comment: @farjam You need to change the `select a date` (from your screenshot)  to `Enter a relative date`. Then enter a relative date in the `relative date` field. e.g. `this month`, `eighth month` etc. See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: Thanks for the help, but in the actual filter that produces (when I set it to exposed), it defaults to current month, but still shows year too. My goal is for an admin to go to that view, select a month, and be able to view all users who were born in that month. He can then switch to another month and view users born in the other month.

Comment: @farjam In that case these links below may help you display only _month_ in the exposed filter: [link1](https://www.drupal.org/node/1394248#comment-7466666) [link2](http://upskill.co.in/content/change-views-exposed-date-filter-month-only)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
/**
 * Impliments hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter
 *
 * Used to change exposed date filter to month only, as this is not available in the views UI
 */
function MODULENAME_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  if( $form['#id'] == 'form_id') {
    // Switch date formatter to month only
    $form['field_date']['value']['#date_format'] = 'm';
    // Add extra validator to handle filter submit
    $form['#validate'][] = 'MODULENAME_views_exposed_form_validate';
  }
}
/**
 * Custom validator for exposed date filter
 */
function MODULENAME_views_exposed_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $handlers = &$form_state['view']->filter;
  foreach ($handlers as $key => $handler) {
    if (!empty($handler->options['exposed'])
     && isset($form[$key]['value']['#type'])
     && $form[$key]['value']['#type'] == 'date_select'
     && $form[$key]['value']['#date_format'] == 'm'){
      $handler->options['granularity'] = 'month';
      $handler->format = 'm';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use a hook you can do it with a more simple solution (works for D7, D8, D9).

1. Add the month field to your view.
2. Use the custom php format date that you need for exposing the month
   [image: custom php format for month]
3. On the FILTER CRITERIA add and expose Global: Combine fields filter for the month and group them
   [image: combine filter for month]
4. Hide the month field from the results using CSS (adding a class for hide)
5. Repeat the 1-4 steps for the year field

It takes a little longer to set up, this might work better for the month than the year field since month are always the same, but years might need to be updated manually (adding years)
[![enter image description here][3]][3]